# Foreach loop NOT appending to array

Tags: php, arrays

As you can see below, I am going through an array called $subLinks, taking each as a $subLink, and adding it to the array called $linkArray, if it is not already there.

However on each iteration of the loop, $linkArray is cleared and starts from the beginning. So for example at the end of each loop $linkArray echos a list of links, and on the second loop that list of links is cleared and replaced with the links of the next $subLink.

My aim is to end up with one big array containing every $subLink - without duplicates,

```
    $linkArray = array();
    foreach($subLinks as $subLink){

      # Validate and clean the links found
      $subLink = cleanUrl($url,$subLink);

      if(!in_array($subLink,$linkArray)){
        $linkArray[2] = $subLink;
      }

      echo($linkArray[2].'<br />');
      flushOutputBuffer();

    }
```

An example of what is echoed is:

```
link1
link2
link3
```

At the next loop, this is echoed:

```
link1
link2
link3
```

What I'd like, is if it's not a duplicate, to add to the array, like this

```
link1
link2
link3
link4
link5
```

Any help really appreciated here,

Thanks

Update: The array seems to reset after 110 elements, and overwrites previous entries

Answer (score 1):

You are always assigning the new link to `[2]` and overwrite the contents of `[2]` again and again and again, try this instead:

```
//...
if(!in_array($subLink, $linkArray)){
    $linkArray[] = $subLink;
}
//...
```

This will append the new link to the end of an array.

Comment: This still isn't working for me, when I do a print_r at the end of each loop, it only displays the new links

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the items correctly. To populate an array, you would need to write

```
$linkArray[] = $subLink; // do not specify an index
```

Of course this is all moot, because there is a much, much better way of achieving the same result:

```
$linkArray = array_unique(array_map(
                 function($item) use($url) { return cleanUrl($url, $item); }, $subLinks
             ));
```

Comment: Hi again Jon! the code you gave me results in this for me: array_map() expects at least 2 parameters, i'm sure i'm doing something wrong

Comment: @user964145: Forgot to add second parameter, sorry. Have a look again.

Comment: jesus the speed difference is ridiculous, but it's still not working for me, i've edited my initial post to show my code according to yours, let me now what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @user964145: Lose the `foreach` as well, and provide more information on how it's not working.

Comment: still not working without foreach, for each $subLink it's adding each value to the new array, when that array is print_r'd it shows the links only for that $subLink, whereas I want to keep adding to the new array, instead of replacing with just the links of the $subLink, so the new array ends up populated with every possible $subLink, not just the last

Comment: alright i've just realised a problem, the array seems to reset after the 110th element

Answer (score 0):

Um, because you're overwriting it in each loop? You write to the same index over and over again

If you want to append to the index, do it like this:

$yourVar[2][] = $valueToAppend

Comment: I was hoping to append to the same index over and over again :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to get rid of duplicate entries, first just add every sublink to the link array; then simply use the function below to get rid of any duplicates. It's a one step process and one of the fastest ways to get unique data in your array.

The array_unique() function removes duplicate values from an array. If two or more array values are the same, the first appearance will be kept and the other will be removed.

Syntax

```
Array = array_unique(array)
```

In the end you'll have 'one big array containing every $subLink - without duplicates'.

And thats that. Hope this helps, if so let me know.

**Pk**